# Is it possible to access the Google Cloud Scheduler API using an API key?

Tags: api-key, google-cloud-scheduler

Is it possible to access the [Google Cloud Scheduler API](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/) using an [API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)?

*Method: projects.locations.jobs.create*
https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs/create

I am trying to create a Job using curl:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://cloudscheduler.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/locations/nam5/jobs?key=[MyAwesomeAPIKey]' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "name": "test-awesome-job",
    "description": "My first job",
    "schedule": "45 23 * * 6",
    "timeZone": "utc",
    "pubsubTarget": {
        "topicName": "projects/my-project/topics/topic-name",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "39ro"
        }
    }
}'
```

but it result in a 401 Unauthorized response:

```
"error": {
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
  "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Scheduler API uses service account credentials as described in https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production. As the API docs state, a limited number of GCP services support API keys and that does not include Cloud Scheduler.

If you are running the code to interact with the Cloud Scheduler API on App Engine, Cloud Functions, or Cloud Run the service account is built-in and all you need to do is grant that service account permission to interact with Cloud Scheduler via IAM.

The docs have some more streamlined information on getting set up with [the Cloud Scheduler client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/libraries).

Answer (score 1):

I get confused watching the API explorer which suggested as possible credentials
Google OAuth 2.0 or API key and from the "Help me choose" tool from Google Cloud API credentials (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials), which apparently now reports the correct solution:

```
For your situation you can use Application Default Credentials, 
which provide a simple way to access Google APIs from App Engine or Compute Engine.
```

previously it showed the API keys as a possible option.

Thanks [@Grayside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38408/grayside) for pointing me out!